# Can't change volume of sound card

Tags: windows-7, usb, audio, sound-card, mute

I got a new external USB soundcard. It's a [Turtle Beach Audio Advantage Micro II](http://www.turtlebeach.com/products/sound-cards/audio-advantage-micro-ii.aspx). It was a simple plug-and-play thing. I'm using Windows 7. The moment I plugged it in, Windows recognized it and I could hear the music. I was able to change the volume and everything. Then I clicked on a few settings or so and now I can't change the volume. I can see the icon in the system tray and I get a volume slider but scrolling the volume slider doesn't change the volume. I can't even mute the darned thing. Any ideas on what could be wrong?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Go into Playback devices and right click on the entry for the headset. Make sure it is set as the default playback AND the default communications device.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe they know?

http://www.turtlebeach.com/support/index.php?View=search&s=1&q=%22windows+7%22&sb=Go

Answer (score -1):

Does the device still play sound? Does it show any errors in the device manager? WHave you tried changing the sound in the sound applet in the control panel as well as the device's software? Do you remember what settings you changed before it stopped working?

Comment: -1...while these are good questions to ask and I hope the OP answers them, they are QUESTIONS - this isn't an answer.  Should be a comment on the original question.

Comment: So if I stated these as "check this and check that" instead of asking, it wouldn't be -1? that is an easy edit. This was not egregiously in error or misleading. Odd that you find an error with helpful suggestions but not with an answer that points to a link to ask the questions somewhere else, considering that is suggested by this site to downvote under the definition of the privileges for voting down (no-effort-expended post).